# Redirect shows up error "Could not create the page"

Tags: redirect, xpages

I got a small xpage containing a button with the following on click event:

```
context.redirectToPage("http://server:8080/AWM.nsf/viewAllDocuments.xsp", false);
```

As soon as I click on the button I geht the following error message:

```
Error while executing JavaScript action expression Script interpreter error, line=1, col=9: [TypeError] Exception occurred calling method XSPContext.redirectToPage(string, boolean)
com.ibm.xsp.page.PageNotFoundException: Could not create the page /http://server:8080/AWM.nsf/viewAllDocuments.xsp because the class xsp.http_003a._002fserver_003a8080.awm.nsf.ViewAllDocuments could not
be found. Please check your spelling.
com.ibm.xsp.page.PageNotFoundException: Could not create the page /http://server:8080/AWM.nsf/viewAllDocuments.xsp because the class    xsp.http_003a._002fserver_003a8080.awm.nsf.ViewAllDocuments could not
be found. Please check your spelling. Could not create the page /http://server.de:8080/AWM.nsf/viewAllDocuments.xsp because the class
xsp.http_003a._002fserver_003a8080.awm.nsf.ViewAllDocuments could not be found. Please check your spelling. Cannot find class    xsp.http_003a._002fserver_003a8080.awm.nsf.ViewAllDocuments in NSF
```

I tried to rebuild the database and did a clean, but nothing changes.
The xpage viewAllDocuments.xsp exists and if I copy the path of the error message and try to open the page directly, that works.

Can anybody give me a hint here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your code of `redirectToPage` by removing the second argument of `false` or setting it to `true`. This should work:

```
context.redirectToPage("http://server:8080/AWM.nsf/viewAllDocuments.xsp")
```

Or you could write something like this:

```
facesContext.getExternalContext().redirect("http://server:8080/AWM.nsf/viewAllDocuments.xsp")
```

When you set the second argument to `false` the redirect happens on server so you would have to write something like this to make it work (this assumes that `viewAllDocuments.xsp` is in same database):

```
context.redirectToPage("viewAllDocuments.xsp", false)
```

When the redirect happens on server the URL on your browser will not update, but the page will.

Refer to [documentation of `redirectToPage`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.api.doc/r_wpdr_xsp_xspcontext_redirecttopage_r.html) and [this article by Mark Leusink](http://linqed.eu/?p=88) for more information.

Comment: That's it! Using the same redirect without the second argument works!

Answer (score 2):

setting the second parameter to false, like you did, obviously tries to interpret your new URL as a resource relative to your current URL (therefor the error mentions "**/http**://...").

Setting the 2nd param to true the new url is appended to your current URL: if you currently are at

```
http://myserver/mydb.nsf/mypage.xsp
```

then the url is resolved to

```
http://myserver/mydb.nsf/http://newserver/newpath.html.xsp
```

At least that's what's happening in my test db on my test server (8.5.3). Don't know if there's a way to prevent that; I usually go either with a link control (if it has to look like a button, no problem: insert an image looking like a button), or I use client side scripting as in

```
location.href="http://newserver/newresource"
```